# How to call getSeason(Months.OCTOBER)?

Tags: java, methods, enums, switch-statement, enumeration

My question is in relation to `enum`s and ***switch expressions***.

I am experiencing difficulties when attempting to call method by using `getSeason(Months.OCTOBER)`.

How can I call this method in main method to print `“SPRING”`? I don’t think the problem is in Season method, but rather in `main()` method.

Code:

```
public class Seasons {
  private static Seasons season;

  enum Seasons {SPRING, SUMMER, WINTER, AUTUMN};

  enum Months { JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, 
    SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER};

  public static Seasons getSeason(Months month) {
    Seasons season = null;
    switch (month) {
      case SEPTEMBER:
      case OCTOBER:
      case NOVEMBER:
        season = Seasons.SPRING;
        break;
      case DECEMBER:
      case JANUARY:
      case FEBRUARY:
        season = Seasons.WINTER;
        break;
      case JUNE:
      case JULY:
      case AUGUST:
        season = Seasons.SUMMER;
        break;
      case MARCH:
      case APRIL:
      case MAY:
        season = Seasons.AUTUMN;
        break;
    }
    return season;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    getSeason(Months.OCTOBER); //How can I print “SPRING” ?

  }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println`?

Comment: `System.out.println(getSeason(Months.OCTOBER));`?

Comment: I also have issues with the fact that the compiler doesn't like the fact that `Seasons` contains `Seasons`, seems to freak it out for some reason

Comment: We already have the [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum. No need to re-invent.

Comment: Are your spring and autumn incorrect, swapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
public class Seasons {
  enum Seasons {SPRING, SUMMER, WINTER, AUTUMN};
```

is giving me no end of issues, the compiler doesn't seem to like the fact that you've re-declared `Seasons`

You also seem to be missing an opportunity to encapsulate some of the functionality, for example, wouldn't it be easier if you could ask the `MONTH` directly what season it represents?

So, I started by renaming you `enum`s so they are plural and then added support to the `Month` `enum` to get the current `Season`

```
public class Seasons {

    enum Season {
        SPRING, SUMMER, WINTER, AUTUMN
    };

    enum Month {
        JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST,
        SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER;

        public Season getSeason() {
            switch (this) {
                case SEPTEMBER:
                case OCTOBER:
                case NOVEMBER:
                    return Season.SPRING;
                case DECEMBER:
                case JANUARY:
                case FEBRUARY:
                    return Season.WINTER;
                case JUNE:
                case JULY:
                case AUGUST:
                    return Season.SUMMER;
                case MARCH:
                case APRIL:
                case MAY:
                    return Season.AUTUMN;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Month.OCTOBER.getSeason());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70734900/642706) is correct. I'll add a bit about naming, and some tips.

We already have the [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum. No need to re-invent.

Generally, an enum should be named in the singular. For example, `java.time.Month` and [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html). So, `Season` rather than `Seasons`.

The *java.time* classes ([JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)) established [some naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html) that have proven to be sensible and handy. For moving from the more specific to the more general, meaning we are losing information, use `from`. For example, [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) offers a static factory method [`from`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#from(java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor)) to produce a year-month value from a date object, etc. So `Season#from( java.time.Month )`.

And consider adding a method to produce a display name, versus the all-caps name of the enum object. For a small specific project, hard-code the result of such a method, for a specific language. If re-using this class, consider adding localization via a passed `Locale` argument as seen on the *java.time* classes. For example, [`java.time.Month#getDisplayName( TextStyle , Locale )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)).

```java
enum Season {
        SPRING ( "Spring" ), 
        SUMMER ( "Summer" ), 
        WINTER ( "Winter" ), 
        AUTUMN ( "Autumn" );
    
    private String displayName ;
    
    Season ( String displayName ) {
        this.displayName = displayName ;
    }
    
    public String getDisplayName() { return this.displayName ; }
    
    public Season from( java.time.Month month ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( month ) ;
        return switch ( month ) {
            case SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER -> Season.SPRING;
            case DECEMBER, JANUARY, FEBRUARY -> Season.WINTER;
            case JUNE, JULY, AUGUST -> Season.SUMMER;
            case MARCH, APRIL, MAY -> Season.AUTUMN;
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
System.out.println( Season.from( Month.JANUARY ) ) ;
System.out.println( Season.from( Month.JANUARY ).getDisplayName() ) ;
```

> WINTER
>
> Winter

By the way, a tip: An enum can now be defined locally, in Java 16 and later. This came from work on [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

Answer (score 1):

Method `getSeason()` does its job correctly, the reason you don't see anything on the console is that the result of the method call is ignored.

Simply do this:

```
System.out.println(getSeason(Months.OCTOBER));
```

By the way, if you are using **Java 14 +** your `getSeason()` method could be implemented in more concise fashion.

```
    public static Seasons getSeason(Months month) {
        return switch (month) {
            case SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER -> Seasons.SPRING;
            case DECEMBER, JANUARY, FEBRUARY -> Seasons.WINTER;
            case JUNE, JULY, AUGUST -> Seasons.SUMMER;
            case MARCH, APRIL, MAY -> Seasons.AUTUMN;
        };
    }
```